# How should I interpret this smartctl readout

Tags: smartctl

I'm running a Debian Jessie Machine with an external 3TB Hard Drive.  The drive has gone offline twice in the last few days, trying to [ls] results in nothing to display, same in Dolphin.

Running `smartctl -a /dev/sdc` results in the following.  Note that this drive is only a few months old, but it holds my fairly large video collection, managed and Viewed using  Plex Media Server.

```
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST3000DM001-1E6166
Serial Number:    Z1F4HXVG
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 065ca347a
Firmware Version: SC48
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Dec 10 21:04:09 2014 GMT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status command failed: scsi error medium or hardware error (serious)
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (  592) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 361) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x3081) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   113   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       55323488
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   092   091   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       55
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   058   052   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       150347021957
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       5157
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       48
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   056   037   045    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 44 (Min/Max 41/52 #7782)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       8971
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   044   063   000    Old_age   Always       -       44 (0 16 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3274h+33m+50.476s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       6233106761
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       8133666728

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Check `dmesg` when the failure happens. Could be a bad cable (or the cable is bent too much).

Comment: What about the `Pre-Fail` and `Old_age` comments and also the `SMART Status command failed: scsi error medium or hardware error (serious)`

Comment: Doesn't look fine to me. Change the disk and restore. (Offline uncorrectable should be the clue).

Comment: Offline uncorrectable is 0, no problem. The `SMART Status command failed: scsi error medium or hardware error (serious)` is probably due to the enclosure not passing on all commands correctly. You don't say how this disk is connected: USB? eSATA? Also running a smart self-test should be done regularly, e.g. via `smartd`, configured through `/etc/smartd.conf` (at least on Debian).

Comment: It is a USB3.0 drive. I've installed smartd, not set it up yet though.  Just had to reboot, going through boot sequence said something about emergency situation and to do `journalctl -xb`, it's not finished the boot sequence, having issues with one of the hard drives, think it's this one, can't remember which is /dev/sdd.  Waiting for it to finish so I can check the hard drive.

Comment: So am I looking at the RAW VALUE or the VALUE?  Offline uncorrectable is 0 in RAW VALUE, but 100 in VALUE.  Which do I need to pay attention to?

Comment: I have a drive with similar issues, what happened with your drive since you posten your question?

Comment: It was running NTFS as I'd used it on an old win 7 machine and moved it over. I backed it up. Formatted as ext4 and has been ok since.

Answer (score 0):

smartctl report problems with your disk device, not with connectivity, so if you use a USB adapter to connect this disk you should consider testing the quality of this USB adapter, they are not all egals, and a lots of them are of bad quality

The first thing I can see regarding this log is : there is not bad sector (Reallocated_Sector_Ct) nor pending sector (Current_Pending_Sector), so the surface of your disk seems to be clean.
However the second thing I see : there is no selftest log. So I suggest you can schedule some extended (long) selftest. It is a good practice to scan the surface for defect once in a while, (let's say one in a month). With a command like this one
`smartctl -t long /dev/XXX` where xxx is the name of your device on your system. If it doesn't succeed or does not terminate properly it may be because of the quality of the USB adapter, in that case try to connect your disk on a SATA port on your PC, at least, the the test purpose only, it is quite easy to mount and umount a SATA device without turning off your PC (except for laptop).

Hope this helps.